# extend expressjs res property

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currenty I am trying to add an error & notice function to my [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) app. I thought that by calling

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.notice = function (msg) {
    res.send([Notice] ' + msg);
  }
});
```

the notice function would be attached to all res objects present in my application, enabling me to use it as follows:

```
app.get('something', function (req, res) {
  res.notice('Test');
});
```

However, the example above does not work. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to call `next` after adding `notice` method to `res`, and you need to add the middleware before routes definition.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.notice = function (msg) {
        res.send('[Notice] ' + msg);
    };
    next();
});

app.use(app.router);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.notice('Test');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to do it the way you described it, however when running the following code:

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(app.router);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.notice = function (msg) {
    res.send('[Notice] ' + msg);
  };
  next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.notice('Test');
});

app.listen(3000);

I get:

TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'notice'