# Is function defiend in app.use can have overhead in high load

Tags: node.js, http, express

I wanted to find some function like `req.badRequest('some reason here')` in **express** but I didn't. I use this approach from stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229959/extend-expressjs-res-property).

One thing bothers me, that I know that code `app.use` invokes each time request happened.

**Look at example:**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('I invoked');
  res.internalError = function() {
    res.statusCode = 500;
    log.error('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, 'some error');
    res.send({ error: true, description: 'Internal server error' });
  };
  res.badRequest = function(description, code) {
    res.statusCode = 400;
    res.send({ error: true, description: description, code: code});
  };
  next();
});
```

**Question:**

I don't know what happens with `res` object in multiple requests(when `use` function have been invoked), can anybody explain me? Can it cause overhead in handling request? If it is how can I achieve this syntactic sugar another way and do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Modifying Express.js Request Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518132/modifying-express-js-request-object).

You can extend the prototype that `req` and `res` come from.  Here's a really simple example I whipped together:

```
var express = require('express')

express.request.badRequest = function(res,description,code) {
  res.statusCode = code;
  res.send({error:true, description: description, code: code})
}

var app = express()

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  req.badRequest(res,'badz',400)
})

app.listen(3001)
```

One difference is that you have to manually pass `res` into this function.  That's because unlike in your example, I don't have the middleware context to get access to `res` via a closure.  This will prevent you from having to generate that function an assign it on every request.

As to whether this is good or bad practice I leave as an exercise for the reader. ;)  I've found that assigning 2 things to an object in every request isn't that much overhead.

Comment: Thank you. Nice explanation. I think it is more elegant solution.